# How to find very first assignment of the variable in python using ast

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to find the very first assignment value of the variable using ast.
for example

```
import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.providers.postgres.hooks.postgres import PostgresHook
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.postgres_to_gcs import PostgresToGCSOperator
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.gcs_to_bigquery import GCSToBigQueryOperator
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator

pg_connection0="airflow_db1"
pg_connection=pg_connection0

with DAG("demo_processing_dag",
            start_date=datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1),
            schedule_interval=None) as dag:

        task1 = BashOperator(
                task_id="dag_report",
                bash_command="airflow dags report --output json >> /home/airflow/gcs/data/parse.json"
            )
        postgres_to_gcs_task = PostgresToGCSOperator(
            task_id=f'postgres_to_gcs',
            postgres_conn_id=pg_connection,
            sql=f'SELECT * FROM public.dag_code;',
            bucket="mybucket",
            filename=f'data/dag_code.csv',
            export_format='csv',
            gzip=False,
            use_server_side_cursor=False,
        )
```

I need a output as
**postgres_conn_id="airflow_db1"**

I tried exploring the ast library but I am getting output as pg_connection="pg_connection0"

below is the code I tried.

```
import ast

input_code = """
import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.providers.postgres.hooks.postgres import PostgresHook
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.postgres_to_gcs import PostgresToGCSOperator
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.gcs_to_bigquery import GCSToBigQueryOperator
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator

pg_connection0="airflow_db1"
pg_connection=pg_connection0

with DAG("demo_processing_dag",
            start_date=datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1),
            schedule_interval=None) as dag:

        task1 = BashOperator(
                task_id="dag_report",
                bash_command="airflow dags report --output json >> /home/airflow/gcs/data/parse.json"
            )
        postgres_to_gcs_task = PostgresToGCSOperator(
            task_id=f'postgres_to_gcs',
            postgres_conn_id=pg_connection,
            sql=f'SELECT * FROM public.dag_code;',
            bucket="mybucket",
            filename=f'data/dag_code.csv',
            export_format='csv',
            gzip=False,
            use_server_side_cursor=False,
        )
"""

ast_tree = ast.parse(input_code)

# find the variable assignment for postgres_conn_id and extract its value
for node in ast.walk(ast_tree):
    if isinstance(node, ast.Assign) and node.targets[0].id == 'pg_connection':
        if isinstance(node.value, ast.Name):

            postgres_conn_id = node.targets[0].id + '="' + node.value.id + '"'
        else:
            print( node.value.s)
            postgres_conn_id = node.targets[0].id + '="' + node.value.s + '"'
        break

# print the output
print(postgres_conn_id)
```

Comment: That's not a variable assignment. It's a named function argument.

Comment: How can I get desired output Barmar

Comment: And to get the value `"airflow_db1"` you also need to model data flow, remembering each assignment and mapping back to the source.

Comment: I don't know the AST library very well. But you should be looking for function call nodes, not assignment nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Walk through nodes in the tree until you find an assignment that is made to a constant.

```py
for node in ast.walk(ast_tree):
    if isinstance(node, ast.keyword) and node.arg == 'postgres_conn_id':
        value = node.value
        while True:
            for node2 in ast.walk(ast_tree):
                if not isinstance(node2, ast.Assign):
                  continue
                if node2.targets[0].id == value.id:
                   value = node2.value
                   break
            if isinstance(value, ast.Constant):
                break

        print(f'{node.arg} = "{value.value}"')
```